# Are there any other alternatives to Report Definition Language?

Tags: xml, templates, reporting, rdl

I am working on a reporting project for which one of the requirements is to accept templates  defining how they want the report to look. So for example one of our clients will consume our API grab some data and pass it back to us with a template defining what charts they want rendered and in what order.

I am currently trying to define that template.

Someone suggested that I check out the [RDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd297486%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) as defined by Microsoft for our report templates. This seems to align with what I need however I cant seem to find any alternatives to [RDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd297486%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and I want to make an educated decision based on everything that's available.

So, I pose the question: Are there any alterantives to [RDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd297486%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you described your "requirements". Otherwise we can only guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It totally depends on the reporting package you use. SSRS uses RDL so for it you pass RDL. For iReports you have to pass JRXML. For Windward Reports (disclaimer I'm the CTO there) you pass a Word, Excel, or PowerPoint file.

You need to let the reporting package you use drive this. And figure your clients will then use the report design tool for that vendor.

Answer (score 1):

JRXML is what Jasper uses for its iReports format.  You can write a report from scratch using it.  As the name implies it is a XML based language much like RDL.  It is robust as it has been around for a while and you can connect to most data bases and Olap data sources while putting all the typical graphics, charts, and tables you would want to see in a report.  Its open source.

There is an open source version of RDL, it is based on microsoft RDL.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/rdlproject.aspx
Several vendors use RDL as the basis of their reports (like Active reports from data dynamics).

Answer (score 1):

There are many different report generators, templates, and languages. FoxPro and Crystal Reports were once very popular.

MS SQL Server has a Report Service that can product reports. Google reveals other options such as XtraReports, Active Reports, Data Dynamics, and Active Analysis.